# Correct way to display snapshot data in flutter with multiple widgets on the screen

Tags: flutter

Im really new at Flutter and Im having problems to display multiples Widgets and snapshot data.

What would be the correct way to display snapshot data inside a Column with multiples Widgets without stacic Height or special scroll ?

I mean I only want to have something like a SingleChildScrollView Where all the other widgets have to move with the _builderViewWidget but when I try to use the SingleChildScrollView I get a lot of errors like:

> RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.

This is my code:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

  StoreDatum store = widget.store;

  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text('HelloWorld')
    ),
    body: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text(store.title, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),),
          Text(store.details, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
          _builderViewWidget(context), <---------------------------- BUILDERVIEWWIDGET
          Container(
            child: Text(store.address, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),),
          )
        ]
      ),
    ),
  );

}

Widget _builderViewWidget(BuildContext context){

  return Container(
    // height: 500.0, <------------------------------------- I DONT WANT THIS
    child: Expanded(
      child: Container(
        child: _productBuilder(context)
      )
    )
  );

}

Widget _productBuilder(BuildContext context) {

  return FutureBuilder(
    future: loadStoreProducts(),
    builder: (context,  snapshot) {
      if(snapshot.hasData){
        return _productWidget(context, snapshot.data);
      }
      else if(snapshot.hasError){
        print(snapshot.error);
        return Center(
          child: Text('ERROR'),
        );
      }
      return Center( child: CircularProgressIndicator() );
    },
  );

}

Widget _productWidget(BuildContext context, product){
  return  ListView.builder(
    // physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    itemCount: product == null ? 0 : product.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, i) {
      return Container(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Image.network(product[i].image),
            Text(product[i].title, style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),)
          ],
        )
      );
    }
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have unbounded height in the vertical axis as your `ListView` will try to expand infinitely.
You can add `shrinkWrap: true` to your `ListView.builder` this will solve your problem.

Since you wanted the whole screen to scroll You will have to wrap Your `Column` in a `SingleChildScrollView` and remove all the `Expanded` widgets. And to the `ListViewBuilder` you can add a `NeverScrollableScrollPyhsics` this ensures the ListView doesn't scroll itself instead the whole screen in scrolled by `SingleChildScrollView`.

Comment: Hi @shubham thank you for your response, I tried and I didnt see difference :( and when I added the SingleChildScrollView to the body I get the described error message above

Comment: Can you remove the `Container` wrapping the `Expanded` in `_builderViewWidget` as Expanded widgets expect their parents to be column or row.

Comment: Likewise, the Widgets around the _builderViewWidget  remain static

Comment: So, I tried your code with little formatting on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/flutter) and it seems to work as expected. Copy the [code](https://gist.github.com/shubham030/5c297ef3dd1729f522877d987bd60bae) and try it and let me know if it works.

Comment: Haha @shubham wow thank you for your patience, but in your example as you can see the store.title, store.details and the store.address remain static, thats what I dont want, sorry if I didn't explain correct

Comment: That's even simpler to achieve. I have updated the [code](https://gist.github.com/shubham030/5c297ef3dd1729f522877d987bd60bae), Have a look at it.

Comment: Thank you @shubham I really appreciate your help!